# Setting Canvas Dimensions and Trying to Maintain Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a simple canvas on an html page and allow the user to modify the dimensions. i also have a rotate button which switches swaps the value of the width and height to rotate the canvas. I do not intend to rotate the elements on the canvas, I just want the canvas size to change.  I have this working but am not getting the outcome I expected.  I am starting with the dimensions 530 x 310 and when i flip to 310 x 530 the canvas looks stretched vertically, much more narrow than it should.

I believe this has something to do with the css value of the aspect-ratio maybe? not exactly sure.  Any help would be really appreciated.  Here's i simple version of my issue.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const widthInput = document.getElementById("widthInput");
const heightInput = document.getElementById("heightInput");
const rotateCanvasBtn = document.getElementById('rotateCanvasBtn');


function updateCanvasSize() {
  const width = parseInt(widthInput.value);
  const height = parseInt(heightInput.value);

  // Calculate the ratio of width to height
  const ratio = width / height;

  // Determine the maximum physical size (in pixels)
  const maxSize = Math.max(width, height);

  // Calculate the scaled width and height based on the maximum size
  let scaledWidth, scaledHeight;
  if (width > height) {
    scaledWidth = maxSize;
    scaledHeight = maxSize / ratio;
  } else {
    scaledWidth = maxSize * ratio;
    scaledHeight = maxSize;
  }

  // Set the canvas width and height attributes
  canvas.width = scaledWidth;
  canvas.height = scaledHeight;
}

widthInput.addEventListener("input", updateCanvasSize);
heightInput.addEventListener("input", updateCanvasSize);

rotateCanvasBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let oldWidth = widthInput.value;
        let oldHeight = heightInput.value;
        
        widthInput.value = oldHeight;
        heightInput.value = oldWidth;
        
        updateCanvasSize();
    
    });
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="530" height="310"></canvas>
  <div>
    <label for="widthInput">Width:</label>
    <input type="number" id="widthInput" value="530">
  
    <label for="heightInput">Height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="heightInput" value="310">
        <button class="btn-square">
                    <i id="rotateCanvasBtn" class="fas fa-rotate"></i>
                </button>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I also thought that it's more narrow than should but I've checked it with screenshot and rotating it and it's actually correct. Have you checked if it's really has wrong size when rotated?

Comment: Your calculations look weird. You could replace all `updateCanvasSize` with `canvas.width = parseInt(widthInput.value); canvas.height = parseInt(heightInput.value);`: You are currently getting the image ratio and then apply the ratio on the same values. Basically you are doing `r = a/b; b = b; a = r*b;`  Baring potential rounding errors, you will always fallback to the same values. `b = b` is obviously useless, but `a = (a/b)*b` is just as useless.

Comment: @AG1, thanks! I did try taking screen shots and you're right they do match up when rotatated.  A can't believe it. This must just be an optical illusion.  seriously, when i look at them they still don't look like the same shape/size.